# FQL my friends who are attending a particular event

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to find all my friends who are are attending a particular event of interest. I think the right way to do it is with FQL. What would be the query to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the example in the [`event_member`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) fql table:

```
SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = ... AND rsvp_status = 'attending'
```

I suppose you could use something like:

```
SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = ... AND rsvp_status = 'attending' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```