# FQL - How many friends are attending to a particular set of events

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

There is a set of `event_id`s. I need to find how many friends are attending to the each event. FB makes that in its suggested events page. Ex. **3 friends are attending to xxx**.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224549/722948) explained for **one** event but i want to take a map like response in a single query. Response like

```
{
 e1:{f2},
 e2:{f3,f1}, 
 e3:{f2,f3,f5,f8}
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You could try using the IN operator to select data for multiple event IDs. If that doesn’t work (or you have to many event ids to query), then you could still go for batched requests to get all the info in one HTTP request. Getting it into the data structure you’d like to have is possible best done in the processing of the results afterwards.

Comment: Since you are looking for a map of events to UIDs, the easiest way is to do it programmatically on your end by looping through one event at a time and following the solution linked in the other example.

Comment: no, i use the [standart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7224549/722948) query and processed it in my own code.